# mysql change HEX number to decimal in LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE

Tags: mysql, hex

all, 
I have a test.csv file with Id in HEX numbers as below:

```
Id, DateTime,...
66031851, ...
2E337E4E, ...
```

The table_test is created using MYSQL as below:

```
CREATE TABLE table_test(
    Id BIGINT NOT NULL,
    DateTime DATETIME NOT NULL,
    OtherId BIGINT NOT NULL,
    ...,
    PRIMARY KEY (Id, DateTime, OtherId)
 )ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

The created table_test is as below:

```
+---------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field               | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+---------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Id                  | bigint(20)   | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| DateTime            | datetime     | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
```

I am using MYSQL as below to load the data in a table:

```
load data local infile 'test.csv' replace into table table_test character set utf8mb4 fields terminated by ',' ENCLOSED BY '\"' lines terminated by '\n' ignore 1 lines SET Id=CONV(Id, 16, 10);
```

Also tried:

```
SET Id=cast(CONV(Id, 16, 10) AS UNSIGNED)
```

and

```
SET Id=cast(CONV(CONVERT(Id,CHAR), 16, 10) AS UNSIGNED)
```

But the HEX numbers with letters like "2E337E4E" do not work. They become some very big number which is bigger than a BIGINT. But when I try MYSQL below:

```
select CONV('2E337E4E', 16, 10);
```

It works as expected with the correct result "775126606". So I think I miss a step in "LOAD DATA" to make the Id as string for the CONV(). Searched for some time, but did not find a solution. 
Anyone has some idea or hint?

Thanks very much

Zhihong

Comment: Please also share the table where you are going to import the data.

Comment: Can you show how you create table?
    show create table tablename;

Answer (score 1):

The typical solution for this type of problem is to load the value into a user-defined-variable, then do the conversion in a `SET` statement.

Something like this should work for you:

```
load data local infile 'test.csv' 
replace into table table_test 
character set utf8mb4 
fields terminated by ',' 
ENCLOSED BY '\"' 
lines terminated by '\n' 
ignore 1 lines 
(@Id, `DateTime`, <explicitly list all other columns>)
SET Id=CONV(@Id, 16, 10);
```